C# Own Auto Complete for Lua
I'm currently working on writing a small auto completer with completions etc. But now I've been at my limit for 7 hours. I have no idea why the suggestions double the first letters, or don't treat them correctly like: llocal function then suddenly comes up. I write this with the package AvalonEdit (For the editor).I don't get any errors either. Would be grateful for any help ^^
public class AutocompleteProvider
{
    private CompletionWindow? _completionWindow;

    public CompletionWindow? GetCompletionWindow()
    {
        return _completionWindow;
    }

    public void HandleTextEntered(TextArea textArea, string enteredText)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(enteredText[0]) || enteredText == ".")
        {
            ShowCompletionWindow(textArea);
        }

        if (enteredText == "\"")
        {
            textArea.Document.Insert(textArea.Caret.Offset, "\"");
            textArea.Caret.Offset--;
        }
    }

    private void ShowCompletionWindow(TextArea textArea)
    {
        if (_completionWindow != null)
            return;

        _completionWindow = new CompletionWindow(textArea);
        var data = _completionWindow.CompletionList.CompletionData;

        AddBasicCompletions(data);
        AddServiceCompletions(data);
        AddInstanceCompletions(data);
        AddCustomCompletions(data);

        AddDocumentCompletions(textArea.Document, data);

        _completionWindow.CompletionList.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab && _completionWindow.CompletionList.SelectedItem is ICompletionData selectedItem)
            {
                ApplyCompletion(textArea, selectedItem);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                _completionWindow.Close();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };

        _completionWindow.Show();
        _completionWindow.Closed += delegate
        {
            _completionWindow = null;
        };
    }

    private void AddBasicCompletions(IList<ICompletionData> data)
    {
        string[] keywords = { "local", "function", "end", "if", "then", "else", "elseif", "for", "while", "do", "print" };
        foreach (var keyword in keywords)
        {
            data.Add(new AutocompleteCompletionData(keyword));
        }
    }

    private void AddServiceCompletions(IList<ICompletionData> data)
    {
        string[] services = { "game:GetService(\"\")", "workspace", "players", "script" };
        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            data.Add(new AutocompleteCompletionData(service));
        }
    }

    private void AddInstanceCompletions(IList<ICompletionData> data)
    {
        string[] instances = { "Instance.new(\"\")", "Vector3.new(\"\")", "CFrame.new(\"\")" };
        foreach (var instance in instances)
        {
            data.Add(new AutocompleteCompletionData(instance));
        }
    }

    private void AddCustomCompletions(IList<ICompletionData> data)
    {
        string[] variableNames = { "myVariable", "playerName", "position", "velocity" };
        foreach (var variable in variableNames)
        {
            data.Add(new AutocompleteCompletionData(variable));
        }

        data.Add(new AutocompleteCompletionData("functionName()\n    -- DEINE FUNKTION HIER\nend"));
    }

    private void AddDocumentCompletions(TextDocument document, IList<ICompletionData> data)
    {
        string text = document.Text;
        var words = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var word in text.Split(new[] { ' ', '\n', '\r', '\t', '(', ')', '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (word.Length > 2 && char.IsLetter(word[0]))
                words.Add(word);
        }
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            data.Add(new AutocompleteCompletionData(word));
        }
    }

    private void ApplyCompletion(TextArea textArea, ICompletionData selectedItem)
    {
        string completionText = selectedItem.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(completionText))
        {
            int wordStartOffset = GetWordStartOffset(textArea);
            int lengthToReplace = textArea.Caret.Offset - wordStartOffset;

            string currentWord = textArea.Document.GetText(wordStartOffset, lengthToReplace);

            textArea.Document.Replace(wordStartOffset, lengthToReplace, completionText);

            textArea.Caret.Offset = wordStartOffset + completionText.Length;
        }
        _completionWindow?.Close();
    }

    public void HandleTextEntering(TextArea textArea, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Text.Length > 0 && _completionWindow != null)
        {
            // Filter
            string currentText = e.Text;
            _completionWindow.CompletionList.SelectItem(currentText);
        }
    }

    private int GetWordStartOffset(TextArea textArea)
    {
        int offset = textArea.Caret.Offset;
        while (offset > 0 && !char.IsWhiteSpace(textArea.Document.GetCharAt(offset - 1)) && char.IsLetterOrDigit(textArea.Document.GetCharAt(offset - 1)))
        {
            offset--;
        }
        return offset;
    }
}

public class AutocompleteCompletionData : ICompletionData
{
    public double Priority { get; set; }
    public AutocompleteCompletionData(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }

    public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource? Image => null;
    public string Text { get; }
    public object Content => Text;
    public object Description => "Vervollständigung: " + Text;

    public void Complete(TextArea textArea, ISegment completionSegment, EventArgs insertionRequestEventArgs)
    {
        textArea.Document.Replace(completionSegment, Text);
    }
}

.
Code Review: Inspected the code for potential issues related to nullability and missing references.
Adjusted Nullability:
Changed _completionWindow to be a nullable type (CompletionWindow?).
Ensured _completionWindow is properly initialized and checked for null references.
Namespace Inclusion:
Added necessary namespaces for Window and AvalonEdit components.
Event Handling Fixes:
Ensured textEditor event handlers (TextEntering and TextEntered) are correctly defined and wired up in the MainWindow constructor.
Revised Autocomplete Logic:
Corrected the logic for handling text entering and completion, specifically for showing and applying completions.

I won't pretend to fully understand what you're doing here, but it caught my eye that in GetWordStartOffset() you have a ! on the first char. condition but not the second. If the second should not also have the ! then the first check is redundant, so that's why I was wondering ...
